# On computers, what is a typographic point, really?

Tags: java, fonts, typography

I know that a point is supposed to be 1/72 of an inch, but in programming, this is clearly not a case. In Java, for instance, I can render fonts to a completely abstract device with no defined physical resolution, and it will provide results. It also appears that a certain font size will always produce the same result in pixels, but that's really just anecdotal evidence from environments I've tested in.

Therefore, I'm wondering: Is there a consistent definition for a typographic point that is commonly used in various computational environments? Is a point in Java generally the same as a point in [Pango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pango) or CSS or other text rendering engines? Is a point consistently sized in terms of pixels? (In some environments?) Will Java/other environments look at the system's configured DPI and try to adapt to that? Are windowing systems even generally well aware of the physical DPI they're rendering at? What about multi-monitor systems with differing DPIs per screen? Et cetera, I guess.

I'm particularly interested in how it works in Java, since that's what I'm currently working with, but if there is a broader answer, then I'm very interested in that, too.

Comment: pt = 1/72 inches. that's physically invariant. A pixel, on the other hand, is physically variant. you can't say anything about a pixel on device A versus device B, without knowing details of the medium in which the pixel exists. what size the display is, what the resolution of that display is.

Comment: The average PC has no idea what actual size the screen is and assumes a default dpi of 96. Hence http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/12644  px = 1/96th inch in css. You can change the dpi setting (those odd never properly working scaling options) but I have no idea how that affects java. But it's apparently not pretty either: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/2d-dev/2011-September/002193.html

Comment: @zapl: Not that I'm questioning whether 96 is the assumed DPI, but I find myself that modern PCs do tend to know the physical size of the screen via the DDC data. `xrandr` tends to present correct information to me. Thanks for the links.

Comment: I do have sizes via xrandr but my 22" 16:10 monitor is reported as some odd 4:3. Besides that, you don't want to adjust for tiny differences because fonts are hand-adjusted to look good at full pt sizes with subpixel rendering, If you were to adjust a 24" next to a 23" monitor of the same resolution you'd end up with ugly unsharp fonts on one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

A typographical point is a *physical dimension*, like centimeters or yards, corresponding to *exactly* 1/72 of an inch.

Whether you're using a book, or a print-out, or a 15" dell laptop, or a 3.5" iphone 4, or a 27" studio monitor, or an 84" plasma TV: 72 (true) points will always measure one inch if you put a physical ruler next to it.

However, you don't generally set text size in points except in typesetting applications, you set them in pixels, which are 100% device dependent. Many APIs will let you specify a text size, and those will almost all be in pixels, not in physical points.

And if you want to know "how it works in Java", specifically, time to use google: find the articles about Java typography, and read through the source code. It's open, and well-documented.